# What is the difference between import css or link css in a React app?

Tags: css, reactjs, performance, import

In a React app I can include my CSS either using `import` or `<link>` it in the index.html file (From a CDN, for example).
What is the difference?
Is there any significant performance difference between the two methods?

To be clear, I mean this type of import from inside a *js or *.jsx file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the only difference between them is that import is the CSS mechanism to include a style sheet and  the HTML mechanism. However, browsers handle them differently, giving  a clear advantage in terms of performance.

Also, using the  tag allows you to define "preferred" and alternate stylesheets. You can't do that with import.

Overall, the  tag is processed more quickly than the import rule (which is apparently somewhat slow as far as the css processing engine is concerned).